# Jquery Id selector not working against Js Id selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a small program to illustrate my real problem I am having.

- Basically, in this program, I am inputting a name and a color and
  they are appended to an unordered list after submit button is pressed.
- Then, I changed the color of the sentence with jquery id selector, but
  the color does not change, but `getElementById` works fine.
- If I input Tom as name and red as color: a red sentence should be output.

Here is the jquery selector version:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 // initialization
 $('select').formSelect();

 $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
  let name = $('#name').val();
  let color = $('#color').val();
  addToList(name,color);
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});

function addToList (n,c) {
 $('#main').append(`<li id=${n}**${c}>My name is ${n}. My favorite color is: ${c}</li>`);
 $(`#${n}**${c}`).css({'color':`${c}`});
 // document.getElementById(`${n}**${c}`).style.color = c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>My Lab</title>
</head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
 <form id="myForm">
 <div class="input-field">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
  <label for="color">Color</label>
  <input type="text" id="color" required>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>
 <ul id="main"></ul>
 </form>
</div>  


  </body>
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 </html>
```

Here I used `getElementById`, and it works:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 // initialization
 $('select').formSelect();

 $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
  let name = $('#name').val();
  let color = $('#color').val();
  addToList(name,color);
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});

function addToList (n,c) {
 $('#main').append(`<li id=${n}**${c}>My name is ${n}. My favorite color is: ${c}</li>`);
 // $(`#${n}**${c}`).css({'color':`${c}`});
 document.getElementById(`${n}**${c}`).style.color = c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>My Lab</title>
</head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
 <form id="myForm">
 <div class="input-field">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
  <label for="color">Color</label>
  <input type="text" id="color" required>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>
 <ul id="main"></ul>
 </form>
</div>  


  </body>
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` in a selector has a [special meaning](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/). You need to escape it. Use [`$.escapeSelector()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/) to do that. Replace this:

```
$(`#${n}**${c}`).css({'color':`${c}`});
```

with this:

```
$(`#${$.escapeSelector(`${n}**${c}`)}`).css({'color':`${c}`});
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // initialization
  $('select').formSelect();

  $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    let name = $('#name').val();
    let color = $('#color').val();
    addToList(name, color);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

function addToList(n, c) {
  $('#main').append(`<li id=${n}**${c}>My name is ${n}. My favorite color is: ${c}</li>`);
  $(`#${$.escapeSelector(`${n}**${c}`)}`).css({
    'color': `${c}`
  });
  // document.getElementById(`${n}**${c}`).style.color = c;
}
```

```html
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>My Lab</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <form id="myForm">
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="color">Color</label>
        <input type="text" id="color" required>
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
      <ul id="main"></ul>
    </form>
  </div>


<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: But the code works only if I use double slashes for escaping the * sign. Why is that?

Comment: @yuvrajprogrammer -- please use `$.escapeSelector` instead. But the reason why two slashes required are because jQuery needs a backslash in the selector to escape it and to create one backslash you require two backslashes in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your `id` is a valid HTML `id`, but **not** valid as a [literal ID in a CSS ID selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) (`#xxx`).

I'd recommend strongly **not** using end-user input to form your element IDs.

In this case, to use jQuery while still using that format of ID, you can:

- Use `getElementById` then `$()` on it:

  ```
  $(document.getElementById(`${n}**${c}`)).css({'color':`${c}`});
  ```

  or
- Use an attribute selector instead:

  ```
  $(`[id="${n}**${c}:]`)).css({'color':`${c}`});`,
  ```

---

Side note: `.css({'color':`${c}`})` can be written `.css('color',`${c}`)` if you like.